# Javascript regex ignoring backslash period requirement

Tags: javascript, regex

For my regex:

```
^(http(s)?\://)?(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$
```

I am wondering as to why `"john"` passes? This regex is only supposed to pass for URLs

```
> var j = new RegExp("^(http(s)?\://)?(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$");
> j.test("john")
> true
```

There is a required `\.` within the regex line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are constructing your regular expression by passing a string to the `RegExp` constructor function.

While `\` has special meaning as an escape character in regular expressions, it also has a similar meaning in string literals.

The `\\` in the string literal has been parsed into `\` in the string and thus is treated as an escape character in the regular expression.

You need to provide an escaped `\` **and** and escaped escape character.

So for a regular expression that matches a single `\` you need:

```
var myRegEx = new RegExp("\\\\")
```

I suggest avoiding the constructor function and using a regex literal instead.

```
var myRegEx = /\\/;
```